SPARC assembly code works, but exits with code 01
I started learning SPARC, and wrote some simple instructions.
fmt2:   .asciz  " 100 - 15 = %d\n"
fmt3:   .asciz  " 100 * 15 = %d\n"
fmt4:   .asciz  " 100 / 15 = %d\n"
        .align  4
        .global main
main:   save %sp, -96, %sp
        mov 100, %l4    !l4=0
        mov 15, %l5     !l4=100, l5=0
!printf(" 100 - 15 = %d\n, minus);

        set fmt2, %o0
        sub %l4, %l5, %o1
        call printf
        nop

        mov %l4, %o0
        mov %l5, %o1
        call .mul
        nop

        mov %o0, %o1
        set fmt3, %o0
        call printf
        nop

        mov %l4, %o0
        mov %l5, %o1
        call .div
        nop

        mov %o0, %o1
        set fmt4, %o0
        call printf
        nop

        ret
        restore

There was an example code on the lecture and I just copied it.
It spewed all the text out and ended with a code 01, and so did the example code.
So I tried inspecting every %o0 and %o1 values with gdb compiler, but failed to understand how pipelining works.
mov %o0, %o1 and set fmt3, %o3 obviously creates a hazard but still works fine.
Is that the cause of the exit code 01?

Why would you expect any particular exit code from this program?  It does absolutely nothing to specify what the exit code should be - you'd need to use the exit syscall to do so.

@jasonharper Or set %o0 to some value before returning from main.

The last printf presumably returns 1, and your main leaves that value in %o0 as its return value.  (But that's odd, printf is supposed to return the number of characters printed.)

How do you link this ? Usually, to get main as entrypoint, Solaris (like other operating systems) will provide a crt (C Runtime - in Solaris, crt1.o) object file that implements the "direct" _start entrypoint and whatever wrapping and setup is required before calling main(). If main() doesn't call exit() itself but returns, then it's also the crt code which will take the return code and transmogrify it into eventual argument to exit(). So ... what the above "returns" (as exit code) depends on your "runtime" here.
